# How to disable usage of Frontpage's _vti folders

Tags: publishing

Frontpage generates _vti_cnf and other folders which are no use to me - Frontpage is slow and my external publishing program can't distiguish regular files and _vti_cnf files.
Is there a way to configure Frontpage not to generate these folders???

Answer (score 4):

If you're not using anything that uses Frontpage extensions, then yes you can get rid of them.

Firstly, turn off Frontpage extensions on the web server. Then in Frontpage under Tools > Page Options > Authoring select "None". Then you can delete all the Frontpage folders that start with a `_`.

Comment: Does not work - the _vti_cnf folder is regenerated when I open a page.

Answer (score 1):

No.  There is no way to stop the Frontpage program from creating those folders.  They are integral in how Frontpage works.

Suggestions:

1. upgrade your computer - Frontpage is an ancient program that should fly on any machine built in the past 4 years.
2. Get rid of Frontpage.  I honestly didn't know anyone has used it since Expression Web came out.

Comment: What does upgrading your computer have to do with Frontpage's folders?

Comment: @TheLQ: The problem the OP is having "frontpage is slow".  Considering how old that program is, it's obvious that the machine is probably ancient as well. Getting a decent machine should solve a number of the slowness issues.  Of course, there may be other underlying problems, really slow internet, slow server, etc.

Comment: I would say really slow internet before really slow computer. But I see where your coming from though